# Cannot connect to SAMBA shared printer from windows computer

Tags: networking, printer, samba

I have quite old printer Samsung ML1660 connected with USB to PC with Ubuntu 20.04. Printer is then shared to network. I can see printer from all 3 Windows laptops (WIN10 home, WIN10 pro, WIN11 pro)

- Windows 10 laptops will connect to printer and will ask for drivers and login. After login with user I am using in ubuntu machine and installed drivers for Samsung ML1660 <s>they pretend, that they can print, but will never add anything to job queue. Nothing will be printed.</s> It turn out, I am an idiot. Server name is server, and it added 2 instances of the printer. One is "Samsung on server  " and next one is "Samsung on server server". I choose first one, and it tried to print locally. After selecting correct one it kinda works.
- Windows 11 will not ask for login, and connection ends with error message "Windows cannot connect to the printer. The specified network name is no longer avaliable"

Pritner settings: in smb.conf

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = yes
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = yes
```

All windows laptops are on same network as ubuntu machine, all have SMB1.0 sharing enabled and all can see and use shared drive from same Ubuntu machine.

After connecting to ubuntuIP:631/jobs I can see two done jobs from last week, but I am quite sure, that this printer never print anything from ubuntu machine. I do not see todays attempts.

I am quite new in linux world, so can you please navigate me, how to make my printer work in the network? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 require SMB version 3 and will not talk to a SMB 1.0 device.

It may or may not partially work for windows 10, but I bet it works better with SMB 3.

Comment: Is there any way to setup printer share via SMB 3? I do not see anything like that in Ubuntu

Comment: in the [global] section of /etc/samba/smb.conf   add "min protocol = SMB3"   Then save and restart samba.

Comment: It allows my window 11 PC to connect to printer, I can print document to Samsung @ server but it stays in queue forever. Never transfer to server

Comment: @110mat110 Try setting read-only to false

Comment: Also try either "min protocol =" either SMB311 or SMB3_11  I am not sure how its supposed to be written in the config file.

Comment: I have tried all of these options and their combination. I can connect to printer, but nothing leave local queue to server :( Thanks for ideas